# If statement not working with indexpath properly

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, if-statement, nsindexpath

I am woundering if I am doing something wrong with this if statement...

I am compairing two indexPaths, and old one and the current selected one if they are not equal I would like to do something other wise continue as normal..

however my if statment is always being accessed even if they are !=.. am I doing something wrong.. I know you can check IsEqual: is here something like that for !=?

heres my code and the output

```
NSLog(@"%@", modelIndexPath);
            NSLog(@"%@", oldCheckedIndexPath);
            NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
            if (modelIndexPath != indexPath) {
                NSLog(@"Not Equal");
                NSLog(@" ");
            }

2012-01-19 16:09:06.521 Code[9907:207] (null)
2012-01-19 16:09:06.522 Code[9907:207] (null)
2012-01-19 16:09:06.523 Code[9907:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc2993e0> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:09:06.524 Code[9907:207] Not Equal
2012-01-19 16:09:06.525 Code[9907:207]  
2012-01-19 16:09:17.921 Code[9907:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc2993e0> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:09:17.922 Code[9907:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc2993e0> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:09:17.923 Code[9907:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc5b0c50> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:09:17.924 Code[9907:207] Not Equal
2012-01-19 16:09:17.925 Code[9907:207]  
2012-01-19 16:09:29.489 Code[9907:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc5b0c50> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:09:29.490 Code[9907:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc5b0c50> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:09:29.491 Code[9907:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc7886c0> 2 indexes [9, 2]
2012-01-19 16:09:29.491 Code[9907:207] Not Equal
2012-01-19 16:09:29.492 Code[9907:207]  
2012-01-19 16:09:34.945 Code[9907:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc7886c0> 2 indexes [9, 2]
2012-01-19 16:09:34.946 Code[9907:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc7886c0> 2 indexes [9, 2]
2012-01-19 16:09:34.946 Code[9907:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc89e780> 2 indexes [9, 2]
2012-01-19 16:09:34.947 Code[9907:207] Not Equal
2012-01-19 16:09:34.948 Code[9907:207]  
2012-01-19 16:09:37.601 Code[9907:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc89e780> 2 indexes [9, 2]
2012-01-19 16:09:37.602 Code[9907:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc89e780> 2 indexes [9, 2]
2012-01-19 16:09:37.602 Code[9907:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc94e480> 2 indexes [9, 1]
2012-01-19 16:09:37.603 Code[9907:207] Not Equal
2012-01-19 16:09:37.604 Code[9907:207]
```

UPDate:

here is the current state of affairs with the help of you guys

```
NSLog(@"%@", modelIndexPath);
            NSLog(@"%@", oldCheckedIndexPath);
            NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);

            if ( [modelIndexPath isEqual:indexPath] ) NSLog(@"hurray!");
            if ( ![modelIndexPath isEqual:indexPath] ) NSLog(@"bummer");
            NSLog(@" ");



2012-01-19 16:41:54.853 Code[11071:207] (null)
2012-01-19 16:41:54.854 Code[11071:207] (null)
2012-01-19 16:41:54.855 Code[11071:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc21f9a0> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:41:54.856 Code[11071:207] bummer
2012-01-19 16:41:54.856 Code[11071:207]  
2012-01-19 16:41:59.637 Code[11071:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc21f9a0> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:41:59.637 Code[11071:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc21f9a0> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:41:59.638 Code[11071:207] <NSIndexPath 0x6a73e10> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:41:59.639 Code[11071:207] hurray!
2012-01-19 16:41:59.639 Code[11071:207]  
2012-01-19 16:42:05.492 Code[11071:207] <NSIndexPath 0x6a73e10> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:42:05.493 Code[11071:207] <NSIndexPath 0x6a73e10> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:42:05.494 Code[11071:207] <NSIndexPath 0x6aae9d0> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:42:05.494 Code[11071:207] hurray!
2012-01-19 16:42:05.495 Code[11071:207]  
2012-01-19 16:42:10.901 Code[11071:207] <NSIndexPath 0x6aae9d0> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:42:10.902 Code[11071:207] <NSIndexPath 0x6aae9d0> 2 indexes [9, 0]
2012-01-19 16:42:10.902 Code[11071:207] <NSIndexPath 0xc625470> 2 indexes [9, 2]
2012-01-19 16:42:10.903 Code[11071:207] bummer
```

Comment: For clarity, you could remove the line printing out `oldCheckedIndexPath`, since it has nothing to do with your if statements. Then you will readily see that it is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those `NSIndexPath` things are objects, and you are comparing their memory addresses. In other words, both `modelIndexPath` and `indexPath` are *pointers*. (google is your friend)

To compare these objects, use:

```
if ( [modelIndexPath isEqual:indexPath] ) NSLog(@"hurray!");
```

or

```
if ( ![modelIndexPath isEqual:indexPath] ) NSLog(@"bummer");
```

to test for inequality.

Comment: what dose this mean.. because it seems to call the correct if statements at the correct time. What is testing for inequality?

Comment: @C.Johns "testing for inequality" is the same as "checking if things are not equal". Please show your code+log with the `isEqual:` stuff in it.

Comment: No my friend you did it! :P lol thanks very much for the help! :)

Answer (score 4):

NSIndexPath is object, compare them using

```
if (![modelIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
```

Edit:
maybe post more code, the code above should do fine, or you can also do, (depends on your need anyway)

```
int modelRow = [modelIndexPath row];
int indexRow = [indexPath row];

if (modelRow != indexRow)
{
    // Do something here
}
```

Note that this will only work depending on your needs!

Comment: see my edit, but that code will depend on what you want to do and might not work for your scenario

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the instance addresses.
Use `if (![modelIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) { //...`

Answer (score 1):

use `isEqual:` instead of `==`

`==` means if two reference point to same object

`isEqual:` means to object are equal

```
if ([modelIndexPath isEqual: indexPath]) {
                NSLog(@"Not Equal");
                NSLog(@" ");
            }
```